# Random "google is not defined" error when creating marker google maps Api (js,c#)

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps

I'm parsing an xml file in c# where I get some lat/lng. Then after that I'm calling a js function where I create some markers :

```
 jsFunc = "createMarker(" + position + "," + HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(infoStations, true) + ")";
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "script" + cpt, "$(function () {" + jsFunc + "; });", true);
```

create Marker func :

```
 function createMarker(position, information) {
         GreenIcone = {
            url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker_green.png",
            size: new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 34)
        };
        icone = GreenIcone;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            icon:icone
        });
        markers.push(marker);

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker, "click", function () {

            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: information });
            if (prev_infowindow) {
                prev_infowindow.close();
            }

            prev_infowindow = infowindow;
            infowindow.open(map, this);


        });
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, "click", function () { //supprime l'infobulle affichée au clic sur la map

            infowindow.close();

        });
    }
```

And here are the scripts I'm including (before js and html) :

```
       <script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAHc6798OWr7qKWWzN8CQWRNTw1IysIw_U&libraries=geometry&callback=initMap">

</script>

         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The problem is that for a same position, there is sometimes no markers, sometimes 10 etc... and I get a "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined"
for each marker missing at this line :

```
 size: new google.maps.Size(20, 34)
```

I tried to move the google map api call at the end of html or at the beginning but there are still errors. Sometimes all markers are displaying well and there is no error. Any idea of the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The page sometimes didn't have the time to fully load so it didn't recognize the google map api call. I just added &(window).on('load',function() to the code :

```
 function createMarker(position, information) {
        $(window).on('load', function () {
           //my logic here

        });
    }
```